# Rails method as a nested resource

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, resources, rest

I'm wondering about the clever way to do this...

I have methods that return a value when passed an an object as parameter, such as:

I'd like to use the exact same methods as a nested resource to call via jQuery/Ajax, like so:

.load('/location/8/average_rainfall')

I understand how to define the route, but how do I tell my method to 'find' /location/8 and use that as it's parameter instead of @location as expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact situation is, but one option would be to use a data-prefix attribute (html5). You can then grab the URL from that with javascript.

So if on a div:

```
<div data-rainfall_path="<%= average_rainfall_path(@location) -%>"></div>
```

Then just grab it with jQuery to make your ajax request.

That is the clever way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use view helpers and controller logic where a model would be ideal. You should stick the average_rainfall method in your Location model, then use that in the view like so:

```
<%= @location.average_rainfall %>
```

Then in your Locations controller use it by calling `/locations/1/avg_rainfall` from the javascript.

```
def avg_rainfall
  @location = Location.find( params[:id] )

  render :json => { :avg_rainfall => @location.average_rainfall }
end
```

Comment: You just blew my mind open. I now understand how to put fat model/skinny controller into practice. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I just pass URLs into JavaScript when generating the view, something like this:

```
var ajaxWidget = new AjaxWidget('<%= average_rainfall(@location) %>');
```

This works for me because I don't need to pass heaps of URLs around. I just pass the base URL into the object and then append action names in JavaScript as necessary to make my Ajax calls. The problem with this is that I can't keep JavaScript completely unobtrusive, so I'd like to see a better answer.